# $\mathbb{Z}$-Module exercise

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, free-modules, linear-diophantine-equations

I am trying to solve the following exercise on basic module theory and I am stuck. Any help would be more than welcome!

So let $M\subseteq \mathbb{Z}^3$ the solutions to the following problem:

$-3x+5y+3z=0$

$-6x+20y+9y=0$

$-3x+25y+9z=0.$

What are the invariant factors of $M$ and $\mathbb{Z}^3/M$? Or, put in other words, what is the structure of $M$ and $\mathbb{Z}^3/M$?

**What I have so far:**

$M$ must be free since it is a submodule of a free module over a PID. But I think in order to answer anything else, I must be able to solve the above system. *If* I knew a basis for $M$ then I could calculate the map $f$ injecting $M$ in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ and then I would reduce the matrix of $f$ using *Smith's* algorithm to something simple. Is there any way to avoid solving the system?  Also, since the "injection" matrix will be part of the identity matrix, in the end both $M$ and $\mathbb{Z^3}/M$ will be free of rank depending on the rank of the space of solutions.

**NOTE**: There is some similar problem which is basically to understand an abelian group given a representation, e.g., $<a,b|2a+4b,3a-8b>$. Are the solutions to these two problems in any way related?

Comment: When you say you are stuck, do you mean that you don't **know** how to solve the system of equations or that you don't **want** to solve it?

Comment: @RobArthan I don't know how to solve it, since I assume I can't just copy the vector space method of solving linear equations. More importantly though, I want to know if it nescessary to solve the system or not. Because my teacher provided us with a very handwavy solution which I am not satisfied with.

Comment: Solving the equations isn't very different from the vector space method except you have to avoid division by multiplying by a suitable factor before subtracting. The [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) method is a way of doing this that yields a very convenient normal form. We can't really comment on your teacher's solution if you can't provide the details and I can't see of any way of using the data in your problem that is easier than solving the equations.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you. The reason I didn't post my teacher's answer is simply because I have to translate it into english and I neither understand it's maths, nor I can put it here verbatim. But it goes something like this: let $f:Z^3 \rightarrow Z^3$ be a map such that $ker(f)=M$ . Then the matrix of $f$ has the same coefficients as the system. By reducing the matrix with smiths algorithm he concludes that $Z^3/M=Z_3\times Z$. I find this completely wrong for many resons. The most important being that $Z^3/kerf=imf$ and (in his answer) $im(f)$ has torsion.

Comment: @DavidHill: thanks for the correction: i've deleted my erroneous comment that was based on a misreading of the OP's outline of the teacher's argument. The key point is that the you need to find the Smith normal form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, $M$ is the kernel of the map
$$
f:\mathbb{Z}^3\to\mathbb{Z}^3,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}-3x+5y+3z\\-6x+20y+9z\\-3x+25y+9z\end{pmatrix}
$$
Using the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ for $\mathbb{Z}^3$, we can represent $f$ above as a matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}-3&5&3\\-6&20&9\\-3&25&9\end{pmatrix}.
$$

If $U,V\in M_3(\mathbb{Z})$ are $3\times 3$-matrices with determinant $\pm1$, then $\{Ue_1,Ue_2,Ue_3\}$ is again a basis for the domain and $\{V^{-1}e_1,V^{-1}e_2,V^{-1}e_3\}$ is a basis for the codomain (both of which are $\mathbb{Z}^3$). The matrix for $f$ in these bases is $UAV$.

If $U$ and $V$ are as above, then they are a product of elementary matrices and these elementary matrices act by elementary row/column operations (since we are working over $\mathbb{Z}$, we can only rescale rows/columns by $\pm1$). Smith's algorithm describes how to find a basis for the domain ($\mathbb{Z}^3$) and the codomain ($\mathbb{Z}^3$) so that the matrix for $f$ is diagonal. My computation shows that we can find $U$ and $V$ such that
$$
UAV=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
I read from this that $M$ is 1-dimensional, $\mathrm{im}(f)\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$, and
$\mathbb{Z}^3/\mathrm{im}(f)\cong\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you. Nevertheless, what I asked is to compute $\mathbb{Z}^3/M$ and that is what gave me trouble. I like the thorough answer and I have upvoted it, but it doesn't adress the main issue on my question. Maybe, from your answer, one could argue that $Ue_3$ is the kernel and therefore compute $\mathbb{Z^3}/ <Ue_3>$ ?

Comment: As I said in the post $M\cong\mathbb{Z}$. I think your teacher is confused and meant $M$ to be $im(f)$.

Comment: Yes, $M \cong Z$ but that doesn't mean that $Z/M=Z^2$. For example, $Z \cong 2Z$ but $Z/Z={0}$ whereas $Z/2Z=Z_2$. I mean that we must know excatly the generator of $M$,not only that it has one. Maybe I am undestanding something wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure I can state this more clearly: Smith's algorithm determines a basis $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ for the domain and a basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ for the codomain such that $f(u_1)=v_1$, $f(u_2)=3v_2$ and $f(u_3)=0$, so $M=\mathbb{Z}u_3$. This yields $\mathbb{Z}^3/M=\mathbb{Z}u_1+\mathbb{Z}u_2=\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you very much for your thorough answer!

Comment: You are welcome.